# Combine ActiveXObject and readAsBinaryString()

Tags: javascript, filereader, activexobject

I would like to code a small mp3 player in my browser. All the mp3 files are saved locally.

So, I have to use

```
var filePath = '...';
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var file = fso.GetFile(filePath);
```

and later

```
var oFReader = new FileReader();
oFReader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

But I get the error, that the object doesn't support "readAsBinaryString()". So, I think the object "file" is not exactly the same object, as expected.

Could you please help me? How can I combine the ActiveXObject() and the readAsBinaryString()?

Answer (score 0):

`new ActiveXObject(...)` will always return an "automation object." This is a different type of host object compared to DOM objects.

Specifically, `readAsBinaryString` expects as a parameter an object of type [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Blob), which may be a DOM [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File) object but *not* an automation object.

However, at the time of this writing, `readAsBinaryString` has been dropped from the [HTML5 File API draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).

Instead of trying to read the audio file, a better approach would be to use the HTML5 `<audio>` tag:

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="YOUR_FILE_PATH_GOES_HERE" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

HTML5 audio tag reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/audio

Please be sure to check if your browser supports the desired audio format. For instance, not every browser will support "mp3." If you're discussing ActiveX objects, presumably you're using Internet Explorer which should support mp3 files from version 9+ ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ie/hh410106.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! The problem is: I have to read the ID3v2 tags - so, I have to read the binary string... Perhaps I can read the binary string via ActiveXObject() and send this to the ID3-read-function

Comment: It was actually Microsoft that proposed dropping readAsBinaryString() because it was inefficient compared to storing it with ArrayBuffer. Therefore, the equivalent method would be [readAsArrayBuffer()](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#readAsArrayBuffer). For compatibility purposes, I would recommend writing a function that properly detects which method is available and implementing both - with a preference for readAsArrayBuffer() if it's available.

Comment: Just to understand it right... when I use readAsArrayBuffer(), a Blob object is still necessary, right?

Comment: Yes, according to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#readAsArrayBuffer).